# MySQL Update set

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, crud

Всем привет. Такая задача:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `colum` = (SELECT * FROM `table2 WHERE visible = 1 LIMIT 0,1) WHERE `id` = 12`
```

Все работает пока возвращает один ответ. Если же убрать `LIMIT` начинает ругаться что ответ не один. Можно ли как то превратить ответ в строку. Чтобы работало без `LIMIT` 
(пожалуйста не спрашивайте зачем мне это нужно)

Comment: а что должно случиться если в table2 больше одной строки? Помимо того, что приравнивание полю select * вообще выглядит странно.

Comment: @Мелкий если больше одной строки они должны все и сканкатонироваться в одну строку и присвоится `name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку необходимо поле нескольких строк сконкатенировать в одно значение (приму за данность что это поле так же текстовое и называется `name`) - то пригодится функция [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `colum` = (
  SELECT group_concat(name) FROM `table2 
  WHERE visible = 1
) WHERE `id` = 12
```

Если не указан другой `separator` то значения строк будут разделены запятой. Другой разделитель можно указать синтаксисом

```
group_concat(name SEPARATOR ' ')
```

Необходимо обратить внимание, что `group_concat` имеет верхний лимит размера результирующей строки: он определяется переменной `group_concat_max_len`. При превышении этого размера строка будет усечена в конце.